# Finding the Area Between 2 Curves -- One Intersection Point?

Tags: calculus, area, curves

I'm struggling to find the solution to the following problem: Find the area of the region enclosed by the graphs of $y^2=x+8$ and $y^2=4-x$.

My initial thought was to square root both equations and set them equal to each other. Then square the $\sqrt{x+8}=\sqrt{4-x}$. However, I am only getting one intersection point, $x=-2$.

How do I proceed with the problem if I only have one boundary?

Comment: Draw a picture! Then you will see both intersections. To do the problem algebraically, don't start by taking square roots. First figure out $x$. Then find two values for $y$.

Comment: Why is it necessary to solve for y in this case?

Comment: Try to think about  _solving the problem_  rather than about whether to "square root" to use or what to "solve for". You're asked to find an area. What does it look like? The picture (in @GaurangTandon 's answer) shows you there are two values of $y$ for a single value of $x$. You need those values to set up the integral for the area.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact **two** points of intersection. Remember that a square root is both positive and negative. The points are: (spoiler)

> $(-2, \sqrt{6})$ and $(-2, -\sqrt{6})$

**Graph for reference:**

[image]

Note that you must always first draw a rough sketch of the functions whose area you're supposed to compute. Drawing the rough sketch would immediately tell you that both functions are symmetric about the x-axis (which was also evident from their original equations). So, there must be even number of points of intersection.

Comment: The points are $(-2,\pm\sqrt{6})$. Please fix.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks for the prompt notif. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

When $x=-2$ you have $y^2=6,$ so $y=\pm \sqrt{6}.$

Comment: Why was it necessary to solve for y?

Comment: Because the two intersection points have different y values, but the same x value